# Does exist built-in function in Python to find best value that satisfies some condition?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

Does exist built-in function in Python, that can find best value that satisfies some condition (specified by a funciton)? For example something instead this code:

```py
def argmin(seq, fn):
    best = seq[0]; best_score = fn(best)
    for x in seq:
        x_score = fn(x)
        if x_score < best_score:
            best, best_score = x, x_score
    return best
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I presume by 'best' you mean highest, in which case the answer is simple - [`max()`](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#max).

It takes a `key` argument, which would be your function.

```
max(data, key=score)
```

Naturally, if 'best' means lowest, as DSM points out, then you just want [`min()`](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#min) instead, it does what it says on the tin.

Comment: I think the OP's after min, not max: the code returns the minimizing value.

Answer (score 1):

In general, you want the [reduce](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#reduce) function, but like [@Lattyware said](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16363749/783412) earlier, your specific example, `max` will suffice.

Comment: Just as a pedantic note, it's generally best to link to answers as 'above' doesn't mean much when the list of answers can move based on scores. Just hit 'share' below the post to get a link. It might even net you [a badge](http://stackoverflow.com/badges/260/announcer).

Answer (score 0):

If all you want is a strict optimization of one parameter, max and min work perfectly fine. That said, most interesting problems (in my opinion) rely on the optimization of at least two parameters at once according to some cost parameter. For any kind of non-linear optimization I would highly recommend scipy's optimize module. Documentation for that can be found [here](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/optimize.html).

SLSQP is the most flexible optimization algorithm, so that may be helpful to you.

Comment: scipy's not built-in, which is what OP asked for,

Comment: True, but I feel like numpy and scipy aught to be included in any serious python user's arsenal by default.